# I am unable to connect Node to ArangoGraph

Tags: javascript, node.js, nosql, arangodb, arangojs

I am new to Node js and Arango DB. I am trying to connect my node app to ArangoDB and there seems to be a connection issue which I cannot figure out.

Version - Node v20.9.0, arangojs/8.6.0, Arango DB 3.11

```
    import { Database, aql } from "arangojs";
    //establish connection to the database
    const db = new Database({
    url: "https://755024bd022c.arangodb.cloud:8529",
    databaseName: "travel_Lf11ugoI",
    auth: { username: "root", password: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" },
    });

    //check if connection is established

    const result = await db.exists();

    if (result) {
    console.log("Database exists");
    } else {
    console.log("Database does not exist");
    }
```

[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvv1P.png)
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6tD5.png)